# How do i correctly rewrite this function using list comprehension?

Tags: python

Given the function

```
def line2fields(line):
fields = []
i = 1
while i < len(line):
    fields.append(line[i:i+23])
    i += 24
return fields
```

Rewritten in list comprehension:

```
def line2fields(line):
fields = []
i = 1
while i < len(line):
    yield i 
i += 24
```

I am still learning python and want to know if i got this list comprehension right?

Comment: You haven’t used list comprehension in either example. Check here to see the syntax https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

Comment: `return [line[i:i+23] for i in range(1, len(line), 24)]`…?

Comment: @Joe thank you..seeing they used `for`  loop, does the same apply to `while` loop as in thre example?

Comment: @GodwiinLeke A while loop is not possible inside of list comprehension.

Comment: @deceze thank you, sorry but where does this go? 1st code block or 2nd code block

Comment: Either block can be completely replaced by this.

Comment: @deceze Oh alright 
so how's this:

`def line2fields(line):
    return [line[i:i+23] for i in range(1, len(line), 24)]`

Comment: Yup, that's it.